# ReportServerTempDB log file - Always on availability group best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a 2 node 2019 SQL always on high availability group.  We have the ReportServerTempDB synchronised but not backed up.  It is set to full recovery mode.

The log file has grown to 850gb.  I am looking at what options available to me as this is going to fill up our log disk soon.  I know why the log file has filled up - lots of reports have been generated lately.

Can I set the recovery mode to simple, shrink the log and then add it the backups?  Will shrinking the logs cause any issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just set it to Simple recovery model - after all it's for temporary data, nothing is persisted here it does not need to be in an AG, according to the documentation you can delete the contents at any time. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: I have indeed read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/backup-and-restore-operations-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver16.  Unfortunately it makes no reference to an AG.  It does feel a bit like I am over complicating it.

ETA - of course it does - 1st line in the doc! DOH

Comment: It is here where there is no mention of the AG, just that it can be set to Simple mode.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/backup-and-restore-operations-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I'm not sure why it would need to make reference to an availability group scenario - it does clearly document the only need to backup the database up is to restore its structure in the event of hardware failure - the content does not need to be persisted and so obviously (I hope) does not need to be part of AG replication.

Comment: Thanks - my initial thought was along those lines when I'd read the documents, it was the AG scenario that threw me a little.  
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yup if you implement the recommendation to use simple recovery model you could not then add it to an AG since that by design requires full recovery model (I hope you're backing up the AG databases transaction logs regularly on a secondary replica)